# What is expected to see at a router if a virtual machine with a bridged network is connected?

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I try to set up a network with some virtual machines using a bridged network.

- host computer: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.
- VirtualBox 5.0.24
- guest systems: Debian Jessie CLI
- router address: 192.168.1.1
- host pc address: 192.168.1.4

I need to have static IP's. So I set the */etc/network/interfaces* of the guests (every guest have it's own IP):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.1
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

My understanding of a bridged network is, that the VM's connected directly to the router and the router will manage the IP's. After restarting the VM I expect to see this IP on my router status view (called in the browser with 192.168.1.1/info), but the VM isn't listed.

Is this behaviour right? And why?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re not using DHCP, the router has only two options remaining to detect devices:

- Sniff all network traffic – not really viable with limited CPU power; limited use with switches
- Use connection tracking table, which exists anyway for NAT

This means your virtual machine will show up once it connects to the Internet. Most Linux distributions won’t use the Internet by themselves.

Just setting up the network connection is possible without communicating at all, though usually checks for duplicate IP addresses are performed.

Comment: This means, if I ping from my VM to an other machine or the internet, i should see the IP on the router?

Comment: If you access the Internet, like I said. YMMV however because there’s no standard behavior there.